# Dynamic stored procedure in different SQL servers?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My client wants to change servers from the application, I mean enter new SQL servers name from application and search keywords in the SQL server database tables. I have Stored Producer which is working fine for one SQL server.

If client changes SQL server name in the application level then My connection string in the application will not work. Because database in the connection string that I used is available for one server.

How can I handle this situation? . Is there anyway sp that will be dynamic? P

Comment: Don't allow them to change the server? Why would you do that? I suppose you can create a mirror for the database.

Comment: client wants to search keywords in different servers.

Comment: Wow. Then you need to have your app know which server to check, and change the `SqlConnection` properties dynamically based on which server the client selects. You can store both servers as connection strings in your config file, and reference the appropriate one when building the connection.

Comment: I suggest re-wording the question to reflect what you actually need: you have the same stored procedure on two different servers, and your app needs to call one or the other based on user input. Does that describe the scenario?

Comment: yes. Aaron. But key thing is .. client can have any SQL server (same network) where sometimes my sp may not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in one server you could create a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that points at the other server. Assuming you have linked servers, on `Server1`:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.ProcedureName FOR Server2_Linked.DatabaseName.dbo.ProcedureName;
```

Now when the app calls `dbo.ProcedureName` in `Server1`, unbeknownst to it, it is actually executing on `Server2`.

If this isn't what you're after I think you'll have to elaborate in your question a bit.

Comment: Myservers are not able to link each other. I mean not defined. I need to check SP is existing on my server if not create new one database and execute it.

Comment: What will generate the code for this stored procedure? Do you mean you want your app to try and execute a stored procedure on one server, but if it doesn't find it there, go grab the stored procedure definition from the other server, and create it, then execute it? This doesn't sound like something your *application* should be doing. If you need the stored procedure in both places, *you* should be doing that now.

Comment: For example, you could backup your database, restore it on the new server, update the connection string, wipe your hands, and wish them good luck.

Comment: If the problem is that the connection string is hard-coded in the application and you can't recompile it because you don't have the source code, (1) don't ever do that again, and (2) you could use an alias in client network utility or DNS to make the new server look like the old server once the old server is offline.